# write.table() append argument

Tags: r, append, write.table

When i run the following code the csv file has the 'DF' data frame followed by an 'x' on the next row then 'notes' on the row after.

Why is it outputting the 'x' and is there a way to stop it doing that? I want just the data frame followed by 'notes'.

```
DF <- data.frame(numbers=1:3, letters=c("a","b","c"))
write.table(DF, file="filename.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)

write.table( "notes", file="filename.csv", append=TRUE, sep=",", 
row.names=FALSE)
```

output:

```
numbers letters
1       a
2       b
3       c
x
notes
```

Comment: `col.names = FALSE`, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `write.table` says this:

> x: 
>   the object to be written, preferably a matrix or data frame. If not, it is attempted to coerce x to a data frame.

Since you don't pass a data.frame, this happens internally:

```
x <- "notes"; x <- data.frame(x)
```

This creates the `x` as a column name:

```
print(x)
      x
1 notes
```

You can set `col.names = FALSE` to prevent writing it to the file.